# Writing a batch-file to kill process: f.lux when opening color sensitive work

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I'm trying to produce a batch file that can check to see if a process is running such as a game, photoshop, or media and terminate a specific process. In this case 'f.lux' considering it dims the screen and can affect color quality. I've looked for some answers on here for this with no luck, as most of the content is older and I'm not sure how much has changed in Windows 10. So far here is what I have picked up off of some other posts.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq example_process.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "example_process.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" taskkill /im f.lux.exe
```

Not sure how correct this is, so any advice or help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget that just like war, batch never changes.

Comment: I could have sworn f.lux had an option to temporarily itself for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill /im f.lux.exe
```

either this or

```
taskkill /f /im f.lux.exe
```

See `taskkill/?`

Answer (score 0):

Just change to your task to be killed instead of `iexplore.exe` task in this example :

```
@echo off
set task=iexplore.exe
set Active_task=0
for /f %%q In ('tasklist') DO (if /i "%%q" EQU "%task%" set Active_task=1)
if %Active_task% EQU 1 (
    Taskkill /PID %task% /F
)
Pause
```